# Bug/Poor user experience for the reviewer when closed question is undeleted

Tags: bug

Something is wrong here - either a design bug or glitch https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25667581

What is happening: This question appears to have been un-deleted. On the reopen votes page, it says "added 3154 characters in body" but it shows no changed text. This is confusing.

What is expected: I think questions that are un-deleted should not even be moved into the reopen votes queue automatically, because the reason why they were closed theoretically hasn't changed. But at the very least it should show some question content.

Update: It seemed to have happened again, this time without an un-deletion I think. https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25689703 - the edits are missing again.

> [image]

Comment: *"I think questions that are un-deleted should not even be moved into the reopen votes queue automatically"* ... the question is in this queue because OP edited it, where he added those 3154 characters before deleting and then un-deleting the question.

Comment: @Tom yes, that seems to be correct. So the missing edits are the main issue it seems

Comment: Correct. It looks like it just checks the latest change in the post history to build the diff and not the diff between "version closed" to "latest version".

Comment: The question was deleted and then undeleted after the edit. It spent a total of 7 seconds in the deleted state. That makes it *very* unlikely that the post would be removed by the task which checks on the state of posts and adds/removes them from the review queues. Thus, it's still in the reopen review queue from when it was edited. I suspect that the query which creates the HTML for the review is trying to fetch the diff view, but not the change comment, from the last entry/entries in revision history, which includes deleted/undeleted state change entries.